# how to create a dataset from three files on disk with datasets library in python?

Tags: python, pandas, huggingface-datasets

I have three files under the name train.xlsx and validation.xlsx and test.xlsx on disk.
And I need to have a dataset with datasets library with these three files.
Here is my code:

```
from google.colab import drive
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd
drive.mount('/content/drive')
train_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/train.xlsx')
validation_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/valid.xlsx')
test_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/test.xlsx')

print(train_data.shape)
print(validation_data.shape)
print(test_data.shape)
```

Now I need to have a dataset with these keys from corresponding files:
dataset['train'] and dataset['validation'] and dataset['test']
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
import pandas as pd
import os

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/')

train_data = 'train.xlsx'
validation_data = 'valid.xlsx'
test_data = 'test.xlsx'

paths = [train_data, validation_data , test_data ]
dfs = {p: pd.read_excel(p) for p in paths}
```

Update:
You can create a dataset from three files on disk using the datasets library in Python as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd

# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Load train, validation, and test data
train_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/train.xlsx')
validation_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/valid.xlsx')
test_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/NLP-Datasets/Question2_Data/test.xlsx')

# Convert data to dictionary format
train_dict = train_data.to_dict(orient='list')
validation_dict = validation_data.to_dict(orient='list')
test_dict = test_data.to_dict(orient='list')

# Create a dataset from the data
dataset = Dataset.from_dict({
    'train': train_dict,
    'validation': validation_dict,
    'test': test_dict
})

# Print the shapes of the data
print(dataset['train'].shape)
print(dataset['validation'].shape)
print(dataset['test'].shape)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to create the correct path. As I mentioned my files are on my google drive and I need the absolute path. But your code just uses 'train.xlsx' and two others. How can I create the absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
train_data = train_data.values.tolist()
validation_data = validation_data.values.tolist()
test_data = test_data.values.tolist()
d = {'train_data ' : train_data ,
'validation_data ' : validation_data ,
'test_data ' : test_data 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

It is worth noting that `.values.tolist()` works if these dataframes have one column, if there isn't one, specify it EX.: `train_data ['COLUMN'].values.tolist()`

Comment: Why did you try to create a list for each dataset?

Comment: @HosseinSedghian to be able to join the values ​​in a single dataset and each dataframe in a different column